# Input number in one Frame/Class/Window in a JTextField and show it in a JLabel in another

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am currently working on my own small project in Java to learn and better understand Object Oriented Programming.
It is a Banking Application that allows you to deposit and withdraw money and check your balance, but I think my code is all over the place.

I can't get the value of the TextField from one frame to a Label in another frame. How do I even link two JFrames together?

This is the Balance Class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Balance implements ActionListener {






    JFrame balanceFrame = new JFrame("Balance");
    JPanel balancePanel = new JPanel();
    JLabel balanceLabel = new JLabel("Balance:");
    JLabel refreshBalanceLabel = new JLabel();
    JButton exitBalanceButton = new JButton("EXIT");
    JButton backToMenuButton = new JButton("MENU");
    JButton refreshButton = new JButton("REFRESH");



    public void balance(){

        balanceFrame.setSize(420, 400);
        balanceFrame.add(balancePanel);
        balancePanel.setLayout(null);
        balanceFrame.setVisible(true);
        balanceFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(balanceFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        balanceLabel.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        balanceLabel.setBounds(10,50,80,25);
        balancePanel.add(balanceLabel);

        refreshBalanceLabel.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        refreshBalanceLabel.setBounds(80,50,80,25);
        balancePanel.add(refreshBalanceLabel);


        refreshButton.setBounds(100,220,100,25);
        refreshButton.setFocusPainted(false);
        balancePanel.add(refreshButton);
        refreshButton.addActionListener(this);


        exitBalanceButton.setBounds(100,160,100,25);
        exitBalanceButton.setFocusPainted(false);
        balancePanel.add(exitBalanceButton);


        backToMenuButton.setBounds(240,160,100,25);
        backToMenuButton.setFocusPainted(false);
        balancePanel.add(backToMenuButton);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Deposit depositObj = new Deposit();
        refreshBalanceLabel.setText(depositObj.newBalanceAmount);

    }

}
```

This is the Deposit Class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Deposit implements ActionListener {

    String newBalanceAmount;


    JFrame depositFrame = new JFrame("Deposit");
    JPanel depositPanel = new JPanel();
    JLabel amount = new JLabel("Amount:");
    JTextField amountTextField = new JTextField();
    JButton depositAmountButton = new JButton("DEPOSIT");



    public void depositing() {





        depositFrame.setSize(420, 400);
        depositFrame.add(depositPanel);
        depositPanel.setLayout(null);
        depositFrame.setVisible(true);
        depositFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(depositFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        amount.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        amount.setBounds(10, 50, 80, 25);
        depositPanel.add(amount);


        amountTextField.setBounds(100, 50, 165, 25);
        depositPanel.add(amountTextField);


        depositAmountButton.setBounds(130, 160, 100, 25);
        depositAmountButton.setFocusPainted(false);
        depositPanel.add(depositAmountButton);
        depositAmountButton.addActionListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String newBalanceAmount = amountTextField.getText();
        Balance newBalance = new Balance();
        amountTextField.setText(newBalanceAmount);




    }

}
```

There are other classes and frames but they are not relevant to my problem right now.

Most of the code here is mine and some is from the internet so it all cramped together and it just doesn't work and I'm stuck.

I know the basics of java and am currently doing well on OOP but this one I don't understand yet.

How can I copy the input of the TextField(amountTextField) from the Deposit class into the (refreshBalanceLabel) in the Balance class?

Also, what's wrong with my code and how can I improve it overall?

Comment: You should not be defining Swing components in an ActionListener.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Netbeans section.

Comment: I don't understand?!

Comment: Can you please explain to me what I need to do? I'm stuck at this point and considering trying something else but I don't want to give up. @GilbertLeBlanc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Introduction

Let's see.  I copied your `Deposit` class into my GUI.  It wouldn't compile.  I fixed the compilation errors and added a static main method so I could run it and see what your GUI looks like.  It was a mess.  Why did you make the GUI a fixed size?  Why did you use absolute positioning for the Swing components.  Why in the world do you need three buttons for a deposit?

Here's one way you could create a single `JFrame` GUI that combines the deposit function and the withdrawal function.

[image: Checkbook GUI]

When you create a Swing GUI, you should try and make it as small as possible.  The user can stretch the `JFrame` if he wants it to be bigger.

In order to create a GUI that looks like this, you have to understand how to layout a Swing GUI.  Because this GUI looks like a form, I used a `GridBagLayout` to construct this GUI.  I did not use absolute positioning.

I created an application model that holds account information and transaction information.  The `Account` class holds a name, account number, and balance.  The `Transaction` class holds a check number (optional), date, payee, and amount.

Once I had the application model, the Swing components that make up the GUI were straightforward.  I used one `JPanel` to hold all these components.  I added the components to my `JPanel` one by one, running a test after adding each component.  Not every test was successful.  Since I only added one component at a time, I generally knew where the error was.

As I said in my comment, go through the Oracle tutorial, [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Netbeans section.  Learn how to construct a proper Swing GUI.

## Edited to add

I created a somewhat complete checkbook GUI.  The left `JTable` contains a register of all the transactions.  The right is the control `JPanel` that allows me to add transactions.

[image: Checkbook GUI 2]

I didn't do any error checking.  The date must be input in a M/d/yy format.

As you can see, the balance is updated after each deposit or withdrawal transaction is entered.

The GUI is rather wide at 1309 x 525 pixels.  Maybe the register should be displayed in a `JDialog`, but I like the instant feedback of seeing the transaction appear in the `JTable`.

### Explanation

When I create a Swing GUI, I use the [model / view / controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (MVC) pattern.  This pattern allows me to separate my concerns and focus on one part of the application at a time.

I created 3 model classes, one view class, and 4 controller classes.  Two of the controller classes deal with the `JTable` display, and the other two controller classes are the `ActionListener` classes for the deposit and withdrawal `JButtons`.

#### Model

The `Checkbook` class is the main plain Java getter / setter class that holds an instance of `Account` and a `java.util.List` of `Transaction` instances.

The `Account` class is a plain Java getter / setter class that holds an account name, account number, and account balance.  The account balance is an `int` field that holds pennies.  This ensures that adding deposits and deducting withdrawals don't cause any floating-point rounding errors.

The `Transaction` class is a plain Java getter / setter class that holds a check number, transaction date, payee, description, and amount.  The amount is stored as a double since we don't do any arithmetic with a transaction.

I hope you're noticing a trend here.  All application model classes are plain Java getter / setter classes.  The view will deal with the Swing components.

#### View

The view consists of one `JFrame`, a table `JPanel`, and a control `JPanel`.  The `JFrame` has a default `BorderLayout`, so I put the table `JPanel` in the center and the control `JPanel` on the right.  If you expand the `JFrame`, all the extra space goes to the table `JPanel`.

The table `JPanel` holds a `JScrollPane`, which holds a `JTable`.  The table JPanel uses a `BorderLayout`.  I created a table model and a cell renderer for the `JTable`.  These classes improve the visual appearance of the `JTable` and allow me to sort the table columns by the underlying class.  As an example, the amount columns are `Double` values but displayed as comma-separated `String` values.

The control `JPanel` holds all of the entry fields for a deposit and a withdrawal transaction.  I used the `GridBagLayout` to place the Swing components.  There are quite a few Swing components on this `JPanel`.  Perhaps, I should have made the control `JPanel` a separate class.

#### Controller

I'm not going to discuss the `JTable` controllers.  This answer is already quite long.

I created two separate `ActionListener` classes, one for a deposit and one for a withdrawal. I didn't do any error checking.  By writing separate ActionListener classes, each class remained straightforward and simple.

### Epilog

It took me a few hours to create this GUI.  I coded it one small piece at a time and tested each small piece many times.  I found a couple of errors in the code as I was writing this answer.

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made all the classes inner classes so I could post this as one block.  Copy the code and run it in your IDE to see how it works.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

public class CheckbookGUI implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new CheckbookGUI());
    }
    
    private final Checkbook checkbook;
    
    private CheckbookTableModel tableModel;
    
    private JFrame frame;
    
    private JTable transactionTable;
    
    private JTextField balanceField;
    private JTextField depositDateField;
    private JTextField depositAmountField;
    private JTextField withdrawalCheckNumberField;
    private JTextField withdrawalDateField;
    private JTextField withdrawalPayeeField;
    private JTextField withdrawalDescriptionField;
    private JTextField withdrawalAmountField;
    
    public CheckbookGUI() {
        this.checkbook = new Checkbook();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("Checkbook GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createTablePanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createTransactionPanel(), BorderLayout.AFTER_LINE_ENDS);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        System.out.println(frame.getSize());
    }
    
    private JPanel createTablePanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        String[] headers = { "Check #", "Date", "Payee", "Description", 
                "Deposit", "Withdrawal"};
        tableModel = new CheckbookTableModel();
        
        for (int index = 0; index < headers.length; index++) {
            tableModel.addColumn(headers[index]);
        }
        
        for (int index = 0; index < checkbook.getTransactions().size(); index++) {
            Transaction transaction = checkbook.getTransactions().get(index);
            updateTableModel(transaction);
        }
        
        transactionTable = new JTable(tableModel);
        transactionTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        int[] width = { 75, 100, 250, 250, 75, 75 };
        int totalWidth = 0;
        CheckbookCellRenderer cellRenderer = new CheckbookCellRenderer();
        TableColumnModel columnModel = transactionTable.getColumnModel();
        for (int index = 0; index < headers.length; index++) {
            columnModel.getColumn(index).setCellRenderer(cellRenderer);
            columnModel.getColumn(index).setPreferredWidth(width[index]);
            totalWidth += width[index];
        }
        
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(transactionTable);
        panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        Dimension d = panel.getPreferredSize();
        d.width = totalWidth + 50;
        panel.setPreferredSize(d);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    public void updateTableModel(Transaction transaction) {
        Object[] object = new Object[6];
        object[0] = transaction.getCheckNumber();
        object[1] = transaction.getTransactionDate();
        object[2] = transaction.getPayee();
        object[3] = transaction.getDescription();
        
        double amount = transaction.getAmount();
        if (amount > 0.0) {
            object[4] = transaction.getAmount();
            object[5] = 0.0;
        } else {
            object[4] = 0.0;
            object[5] = -transaction.getAmount();
        }
        
        tableModel.addRow(object);
    }
    
    private JPanel createTransactionPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        Font titleFont = new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 24);
        Font font = new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 14);
        
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel(checkbook.getAccount().getAccountName());
        nameLabel.setFont(titleFont);
        panel.add(nameLabel, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        JLabel accountNumberLabel = new JLabel(
                checkbook.getAccount().getAccountNumber());
        accountNumberLabel.setFont(titleFont);
        accountNumberLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.TRAILING);
        panel.add(accountNumberLabel, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Balance:");
        label.setFont(font);
        panel.add(label, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        balanceField = new JTextField(20);
        balanceField.setEditable(false);
        balanceField.setFont(font);
        balanceField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.TRAILING);
        balanceField.setText(String.format("%,.2f", 
                checkbook.getAccount().getBalance()));
        panel.add(balanceField, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        label = new JLabel("Deposit");
        label.setFont(titleFont);
        panel.add(label, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        label = new JLabel("Date:");
        label.setFont(font);
        panel.add(label, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        depositDateField = new JTextField(20);
        depositDateField.setFont(font);
        panel.add(depositDateField, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        label = new JLabel("Amount:");
        label.setFont(font);
        panel.add(label, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        depositAmountField = new JTextField(20);
        depositAmountField.setFont(font);
        depositAmountField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.TRAILING);
        panel.add(depositAmountField, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        JButton button = new JButton("Deposit");
        button.addActionListener(new DepositListener(this, checkbook));
        button.setFont(font);
        panel.add(button, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        label = new JLabel("Withdrawl");
        label.setFont(titleFont);
        panel.add(label, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        label = new JLabel("Check Number:");
        label.setFont(font);
        panel.add(label, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        withdrawalCheckNumberField = new JTextField(20);
        withdrawalCheckNumberField.setFont(font);
        withdrawalCheckNumberField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.TRAILING);
        panel.add(withdrawalCheckNumberField, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        label = new JLabel("Date:");
        label.setFont(font);
        panel.add(label, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        withdrawalDateField = new JTextField(20);
        withdrawalDateField.setFont(font);
        panel.add(withdrawalDateField, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        label = new JLabel("Payee:");
        label.setFont(font);
        panel.add(label, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        withdrawalPayeeField = new JTextField(20);
        withdrawalPayeeField.setFont(font);
        panel.add(withdrawalPayeeField, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        label = new JLabel("Description:");
        label.setFont(font);
        panel.add(label, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        withdrawalDescriptionField = new JTextField(20);
        withdrawalDescriptionField.setFont(font);
        panel.add(withdrawalDescriptionField, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        label = new JLabel("Amount:");
        label.setFont(font);
        panel.add(label, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        withdrawalAmountField = new JTextField(20);
        withdrawalAmountField.setFont(font);
        withdrawalAmountField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.TRAILING);
        panel.add(withdrawalAmountField, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        button = new JButton("Withdrawal");
        button.addActionListener(new WithdrawalListener(this, checkbook));
        button.setFont(font);
        panel.add(button, gbc);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    public void pack() {
        frame.pack();
    }
    
    public void updateBalanceField() {
        this.balanceField.setText(String.format("%,.2f", 
                checkbook.getAccount().getBalance()));
    }

    public JTextField getDepositDateField() {
        return depositDateField;
    }

    public JTextField getDepositAmountField() {
        return depositAmountField;
    }

    public JTextField getWithdrawalCheckNumberField() {
        return withdrawalCheckNumberField;
    }

    public JTextField getWithdrawalDateField() {
        return withdrawalDateField;
    }

    public JTextField getWithdrawalPayeeField() {
        return withdrawalPayeeField;
    }

    public JTextField getWithdrawalDescriptionField() {
        return withdrawalDescriptionField;
    }

    public JTextField getWithdrawalAmountField() {
        return withdrawalAmountField;
    }
    
    public class CheckbookTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                return Integer.class;
            case 1:
                return LocalDate.class;
            case 4:
            case 5:
                return Double.class;
            default:
                return String.class;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return false;
        }
        
    }
    
    public class CheckbookCellRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {
        
        private DateTimeFormatter formatter;
        
        private JLabel label;
        
        public CheckbookCellRenderer() {
            this.formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d, yyyy");
            Font font = new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 14);
            this.label = new JLabel();
            label.setFont(font);
            
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, 
                Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                int row, int column) {
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEADING);
            
            switch (column) {
            case 0:
                if (Integer.valueOf(value.toString()) <= 0) {
                    label.setText("");
                } else {
                    label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.TRAILING);
                    label.setText(value.toString() + "  ");
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                LocalDate date = (LocalDate) value;
                label.setText("  " + formatter.format(date));
                break;
            case 4:
            case 5:
                double amount = Double.valueOf(value.toString());
                if (amount <= 0.0) {
                    label.setText("");
                } else {
                    label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.TRAILING);
                    label.setText(String.format("%,.2f", amount) + "  ");
                }
                break;
            default:
                label.setText("  " + value.toString());
                break;
            }
            
            return label;
        }
        
    }
    
    public class DepositListener implements ActionListener {
        
        private final CheckbookGUI view;
        
        private final Checkbook model;
        
        public DepositListener(CheckbookGUI view, Checkbook model) {
            this.view = view;
            this.model = model;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            String date = view.getDepositDateField().getText().trim();
            Double amount = Double.valueOf(view.getDepositAmountField().getText().trim());
            Transaction transaction = new Transaction(null, date, "Deposit", "", amount);
            
            model.addTransaction(transaction);
            model.getAccount().addDeposit(amount);
            
            view.updateBalanceField();
            view.updateTableModel(transaction);
            view.getDepositAmountField().setText("");
            view.getDepositDateField().setText("");
        }
        
    }
    
    public class WithdrawalListener implements ActionListener {
        
        private final CheckbookGUI view;
        
        private final Checkbook model;
        
        public WithdrawalListener(CheckbookGUI view, Checkbook model) {
            this.view = view;
            this.model = model;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            String checkNumberString = view.getWithdrawalCheckNumberField().getText().trim();
            String date = view.getWithdrawalDateField().getText().trim();
            String payee = view.getWithdrawalPayeeField().getText().trim();
            String description = view.getWithdrawalDescriptionField().getText().trim();
            Double amount = Double.valueOf(view.getWithdrawalAmountField().getText().trim());
            
            Integer checkNumber = null;
            try {
                checkNumber = Integer.valueOf(checkNumberString);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            }
            
            Transaction transaction = new Transaction(checkNumber, date, payee, 
                    description, -amount);
            
            model.addTransaction(transaction);
            model.getAccount().subtractWithdrawal(amount);
            
            view.updateBalanceField();
            view.updateTableModel(transaction);
            view.getWithdrawalCheckNumberField().setText("");
            view.getWithdrawalDateField().setText("");
            view.getWithdrawalPayeeField().setText("");
            view.getWithdrawalDescriptionField().setText("");
            view.getWithdrawalAmountField().setText("");
        }
        
    }

    public class Checkbook {
        
        private final Account account;
        
        private final List<Transaction> transactions;
        
        public Checkbook() {
            this.transactions = new ArrayList<>();
            this.account = new Account("10002939", "John H. Smith");
            this.account.addDeposit(1400.00);
            Transaction transaction = new Transaction(
                    null, "4/1/21", "Starting Balance", "", 1400.00);
            addTransaction(transaction);
        }
        
        public void addTransaction(Transaction transaction) {
            this.transactions.add(transaction);
        }

        public Account getAccount() {
            return account;
        }

        public List<Transaction> getTransactions() {
            return transactions;
        }
        
    }
    
    public class Account {
        
        private int balance;
        
        private final String accountNumber;
        private final String accountName;
        
        public Account(String accountNumber, String accountName) {
            this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
            this.accountName = accountName;
            this.balance = 0;
        }

        public String getAccountNumber() {
            return accountNumber;
        }

        public String getAccountName() {
            return accountName;
        }

        public double getBalance() {
            return 0.01 * balance;
        }

        public void addDeposit(double amount) {
            this.balance += (int) (100.0 * amount);
        }
        
        public void subtractWithdrawal(double amount) {
            this.balance -= (int) (100.0 * amount);
        }
        
    }
    
    public class Transaction {
        
        private final double amount;
        
        private final int checkNumber;
        
        private final DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter;
        
        private final LocalDate transactionDate;
        
        private final String description;
        private final String payee;

        public Transaction(Integer checkNumber, String transactionDateString, 
                String payee, String description, double amount) {
            if (checkNumber == null) {
                this.checkNumber = 0;
            } else {
                this.checkNumber = checkNumber;
            }
            
            this.inputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yy");
            this.transactionDate = LocalDate.parse(transactionDateString, inputFormatter);
            this.payee = payee;
            this.description = description;
            this.amount = amount;
        }

        public double getAmount() {
            return amount;
        }

        public int getCheckNumber() {
            return checkNumber;
        }

        public LocalDate getTransactionDate() {
            return transactionDate;
        }

        public String getPayee() {
            return payee;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: I am seriously impressed with your answer. I feel spoiled. Thank you so much. I will begin to edit my project and learn more about Swing GUI's by using your answer as a guide (as well as the provided link). Thank you!!!!

Comment: @Eduard: You're welcome.  You've inspired me to create a more complete Checkbook Swing application.  When it's finished, I'll post it on [GitHub](https://github.com/ggleblanc2).